# Reference user in Rails Fixtures

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to reference the ID of a user fixture in another fixture. I have a messages.yml fixture:

```
basic:
  body: "Hey Barney, wanna go bowling tonight?"
  sender: fred
  recipient_ids: [users(:barney)]
  type: Message
```

users.yml

```
barney:
 first_name: Barney
 last_name: Rubble
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use ERB syntax:

```
recipient_id: <%= User.find_by_first_name('Barney').id %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Answer (score 0):

This is a big reason why fixtures are not commonly used anymore. I'd recommend using a seeds file. Possibly with [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/). This will allow you to create fixtures/seeds in Ruby and do just about anything.